# Joining, filtering, and paging results from multiple data sources

Tags: java, orm, querydsl

Our existing Java application is built directly on top of Spring Data/JPA/Hibernate for data access. For the most part objects are hydrated by Spring Repositories executing JPQL queries. We also rely on QueryDSL when more dynamic querying and sorting is required. Spring Data plays very nicely with QueryDSL and all of the nice paging/sorting you get with Spring Data continues to work well.

We're currently extending the existing system to one where some data is in the database and other data is persisted via RESTful services. The issue that arises is how to efficiently join, filter, sort, and page when dealing with multiple sources of persisted data. Data from one source can refer to data from another source via its primary key, with no integrity constraints, obviously.

I've looked at things like QueryDSL for collections, Quaere, jaque, SBQL4J, and lambdaj but came away with the impression that all data from all data sources would have to be loaded in memory to be joined, filtered, sorted, and paged - not very efficient, especially for a web app. Granted, some data could be filtered, via JPQL, for instance, to shrink the hit in memory usage a bit but this still smells.

**Q: Are there any libraries available that elegantly handle this scenario of heterogeneous data sources and technologies?**

Comment: I don't think there may be, but it looks like you have your answer: *all data from all data sources would have to be loaded in memory to be joined, filtered, sorted, and paged*. About *not very efficient, especially for a web app*, that depends on server hardware, configuration and tunning more than you may think.

Comment: It's literally impossible to sort partial data sets. The only approach available is the straightforward one. Filtering can occur on the individual data sources, and if you're **not** sorting, you could also optimize paging (although I'm not sure it'd be any useful, it'd essentially be picking records from the sources at random.)

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza: That's what I thought. What approaches have you used to minimize the performance hit (memory, DB) in these situations? We really can't cache the data coming from the RESTful services since they're out of our control and also used by other client applications so we're stuck making both REST and DB calls and processing the results for every HTTP request.